# ASP.NET Core 7 certs user name

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, iis, ssl-certificate, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 app that is grabbing the certs subject user below. What I want to get is:

```
string? user = _context.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
```

For this to happen, I just wrote this code in my `Program.cs` file.

```
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddCertificate(options =>
           {
               options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
           });
```

As soon as I add Identity to my `Program.cs`, it switches from certs subject to windows username which I cannot use.

```
 builder.Services
        .AddIdentity<AppUserModel, IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I need to only grab certs Subject (username) when someone selects their certs.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was using two schemes and I needed to use certificates scheme when I am in the login controller.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
 public IActionResult Login {}
```